# Efficiently compute historical aggregates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing historical records, for example sales.

```
import pandas as pd

first_salesman = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=[pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-03')])
second_salesman = pd.Series([2, 0, 5], index=[pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-03')])
third_salesman = pd.Series([6, 7, 1], index=[pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-02'), pd.to_datetime('2015-01-03')])

df = pd.concat([first_salesman, second_salesman, third_salesman], axis=1).reset_index()
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'], value_vars=[0, 1, 2])
df.columns = ['Date', 'Salesman_id', 'Sales']
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

I would like to compute historical statistics for each of the salesmen: in other terms, for each salesman and each day, I would like to know how their mean, std, max, min, etc... looked like until that day.

So focusing on salesman 1 and only the average, it would be [1, 1.5, 2].

I can certainly build a for-loop, but I have a fairly big number of salesmen and dates and this doesn't look like the most efficient thing to do. What I'm looking for is a way of computing this in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I found the solution. In Pandas >= 0.18, you can use df.expanding(). See [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html).

A clean solution to this scenario is this one-liner:

```
df.set_index(['Salesman_id', 'Date']).expanding(min_periods=1).agg([np.mean, np.std, np.min, np.max])
```

Note that .expanding() fully supports .agg() so you can use whatever aggregates you'd like.